# How do I uninstall *all* nuget packages from a solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I know I can uninstall-package from the PM console.
I got into some dependency issues with another project
and I want to start over, and I need to delete all packages in one shot.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 182):

To get all packages from all projects in the solution use `Get-Package`. To get all packages from a specific project use `Get-Package -ProjectName "YourProjectName"`.

#### Remove all packages from all projects in the solution

> Be careful: This will uninstall **ALL** packages in the **solution**. If `-Force` parameter is used, packages are removed even if dependencies exist.

```
Get-Package | Uninstall-Package -RemoveDependencies -Force
```

#### Remove all packages from a specific project within a solution

> Be careful: This will uninstall **ALL** packages in the **project**. If `-Force` parameter is used, packages are removed even if dependencies exist.

```
Get-Package -ProjectName "YourProjectName" | 
Uninstall-Package -ProjectName "YourProjectName" -RemoveDependencies -Force
```

Comment: I recommend to add the -Force parameter at the end. Without it, I can't uninstall all my dependencies based on dependencies with other NuGet packages.

Comment: This is the real answer. Combined with Sean's suggestion to use `-force`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 90):

In Package Manager Console just type:

> get-package | uninstall-package -removedependencies

Comment: To not get stuck in complex dependency graph, use `-Force` switch.

Comment: WARNING: This commend will uninstall all packages within the whole SOLUTION.

Answer (score 37):

try this:

```
get-package | uninstall-package -removedependencies -force
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to uninstall every NuGet Package from every Project in a Solution, then use this in the NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
foreach($project in $projects){ $packages = Get-Package -ProjectName $project.Name; foreach($package in $packages){ Uninstall-Package -ProjectName $project.Name -Id $package.Id -Force} }
```

Comment: Great answer. Script for a single project: `$packages = Get-Package -ProjectName MyProjectName; foreach($package in $packages){ Uninstall-Package -ProjectName MyProjectName -Id $package.Id -Force}`

Answer (score 10):

Using the -Force parameter in my case left project file modifications and references to some binaries that should have been removed when normally uninstalling the packages.

Here is a naive method to uninstall all packages from specific projects without using the -Force parameter. Effectively it tries to uninstall the packages over and over again until there are no packages left, so you will see some errors mentioning dependent packages (if you have them) but they will turn up less and less as the leaf packages get removed each iteration.

Also worth mentioning I've only tested the following PowerShell snippets in the PackageManager console. ("Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console")

**Uninstall all the packages from all the projects in a solution**

```
while((Get-Project -All | Get-Package).Length -gt 0) { Get-Project -All | Get-Package | Uninstall-Package }
```

**Only remove Projects containing the word "*WildCardSearch*"**

```
while((Get-Project -All | Where-Object ProjectName -like '*WildCardSearch*'  | Get-Package).Length -gt 0) { Get-Project -All | Where-Object ProjectName -like '*WildCardSearch*' | Get-Package | Uninstall-Package }
```

Note that if you have another issue apart from dependent packages preventing an uninstall of the package this snippet will run forever until you manually stop it.

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe this is possible so un-install ALL packages at once.  However, as you already indicated you can un-install a package, but you can also tell it to un install its dependencies doing the following:

> Uninstall-Package OpenIdPortableArea –RemoveDependencies

Here is a blog by Marcus Hammarberg explaining this: http://www.marcusoft.net/2011/02/nuget-uninstall-remove-dependencies.html

Comment: "Remove dependencies" works when 1 package depends on many others. It doesn't work when N packages depend on the core one (e.g. Boost). You need to remove the NuGet Boost packages manually one by one, which is a pain.

Answer (score 3):

Auto-restoring (uninstall and install without updating to the latest version) of packages using Package Manager Console:

This runs for the whole solution:

**Update-Package -Reinstall**

... or for specific project only:

**Update-Package -Reinstall -Project [ProjectName]**

Comment: Well, it woulda been nice to know the first command runs against your entire solution, regardless of what project you have set as default in the package manager console window.  I never even looked at the second command until writing this message, ugh!

Comment: Updated the answer to point that out @PostImpatica :-)

Answer (score 1):

Updated a script to remove all nuget packages for single project in VS solution:

```
$projectName = "MyProjectName"; $packages = Get-Package -ProjectName $projectName; foreach($package in $packages){ Uninstall-Package -ProjectName $projectName -Id $package.Id -Force}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dummy old-school for loop:

```
$packages = get-package
$packageId = "Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ"


$counter = 1
foreach($package in $packages){     
    if($package.Id -eq $packageId)
    {   
        Write-Host "`n$counter-Deleting Package:`n"
        $package        
        Uninstall-Package -Id $packageId -ProjectName $package.ProjectName -RemoveDependencies 
        Write-Host "`n============================================`n"
        $counter++
    }
}
```