# How do I uninstall *a* package from all projects in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Not a duplicate [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28596666):

> The other question does not talk about removing one single package
>   from all the projects inside solution.

---

> What is the command to uninstall **a** specific package from all projects
>   inside a solution?

Visual studio GUI still seems to be naive to support these features.

Comment: the one you linked to shows you how.

Comment: @KeithNicholas, thanks for attempting to answer. Are you sure? Could you paste the answer link here.

Comment: Right-click solution, then "Manage Nuget packages".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What is the command to uninstall a specific package from all projects inside a solution?

You can use following command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Get-Project -All | Uninstall-Package <package name>
```

If this package have dependencies, you can add option `-RemoveDependencies` in above command line.

> Visual studio GUI still seems to be naive to support these features.

Right-click your solution > `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`, switch to the `Install` tab, select the package which you want to uninstall, then you can check the first checkbox, all the check boxes would be selected, click the uninstall button:

[image]

This package will uninstall from all projects in the solution.

Hope this helps.