# uninstall / Install Nuget Package across multiple solutions and projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-cli

- How do I `uninstall` a `package by id and version` for all solutions
  and projects under a folder?
- How do I `install` a `package by id and
  version` for all solutions and projects under a directory?

There is a package manager approach with somewhat [Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418856/nuget-for-solutions-with-multiple-projects) that shows how to do that for all projects under A solution.
You can use Package Manager Console from solution and use this for one solution. But how to do the same across multiple solutions and projects under them?

Comment: Right click on your solution, then manage nuget packages

Comment: That's for A solution. I need to do that under code repository, all solutions, all projects under every solution.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376313/setting-up-a-common-nuget-packages-folder-for-all-solutions-when-some-projects-a

Comment: I will put some custom script considering no out the box solution here

Comment: For powershell script, you can try [this similar link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596666/how-do-i-uninstall-all-nuget-packages-from-a-solution-in-visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

> But how to do the same across multiple solutions and projects under
>   them?

**You cannot get what you want at present.**

To uninstall packages, you should only use **Manage Nuget packages for solution UI** or **Package Manager Console** to uninstall one package for one solution. You can not use it to uninstall a package for several solutions at the same time. **VS IDE does not support it.**

**Suggestion**

So you should open a solution each time and run this command on Package Manager Console:

```
Get-Project -All | Uninstall-Package xxx<package_name>
```

Or use **Manage Nuget Packages for Solution**

**Besides**, If you still want this feature, I suggest you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

[image]

You can share the link with us here and anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention as soon as possible.